# Why can't I get this code to work? $ echo mean? "">>/apache/conf/httpd.conf

Tags: awk

When I created the configuration file `apache/conf/httpd.conf` and went to check if it was in the system the program was saying that the file does not exist so how do I recreate the file so that it does exist?

```
$ echo "">>/apache/conf/httpd.conf  
-bash: /apache/conf/httpd.conf: No such file or directory
```

Actually I am doing a school project using "CYGWIN" which is a simulator of Linux and while creating a task from school I got that error.
This is the whole program I was writing:

```
$ if test -d apache
then
if ! test -d apache/bin
then 
mkdir apache/bin
fi
if ! test -d apache/conftouch
then 
mkdir apache/conf
fi
if ! test -d apache/lib
then
mkdir apache/lib
fi
if ! test -f apache/bin/httpd
then
touch apache/bin/httpd
fi
if ! test -f apache/conf/httpd.conf
then
touch apache/conf/httpd.conf
fi
mkdir apache
mkdir apache/bin
mkdir apache/conf
mkdir apache/lib
touch apache/bin/httpd
touch apache/conf/httpd.conf
fi
```

and after I wrote the program and went back to check the files it said file does not exist can anyone figure this out to help me?

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Comment: Create the topic with the correct information before submitting please. You are wasting out time like that :( "Actually I am doing a school project using "CYGWIN" which is a simulator of Linux " we ONLY support Ubuntu. cygwin is windows.

Answer (score 2):

Your directory is wrong: apache is NEVER installed in the root of a Linux system.

It needs to be:

```
echo "" >> /etc/apache2/conf/httpd.conf
```

To make sure do a

```
locate httpd.conf
```

and change the directory to what it returns. Mind that I also assume you are using a new Ubuntu... you likely have apache2 as a directory and not apache(1). The locate will also confirm that. apache was replaced by apache2 ages ago.

You also might need "sudo" depending if you own the http.conf or not.

---

edit:

> and after I wrote the program and went back to check the files it said file does not exist can anyone figure this out to help me?

Please tell us: why does everything in that edit NOT have a / in front of apache and the command that gives the error does have one?

Based on the edit I would then assume it needs to be

```
echo "" >> apache/conf/httpd.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

`>>` adds output to an existing file, that's why os tries to find this file first before writing it. That's the issue, if you will check with

```
/apache/conf/httpd.conf
```

You will notice file not found
Probably you've just forgot to install `httpd` with your package manager